# Perform model selection with step function and write outcome into 0/1 vector (R)

Tags: r, call, modeling, glm, names

I am trying to write an algorithm which does the following in R:

1. On a data set `dat` use `step` function to perform `glm` model selection of j covariates from a set of J candidate variables
2. Take final `call` of j variates and compare with full vector J. Write outcome into a 1xJ vector, where 1 indicates variable is in final `call` and 0 elsewise.

Example:

In the following example three variables (`x,y,z`) are candidates for prediction of variable `dep`. `Step` is used for variable selection. My goal is to finally have a vector indicating which of the input variables ends up in the final model, so here, `c(1,0,1)`.

```
n=1000
x <- rnorm(n,0,1)
y <- rnorm(n,0,1)
z <- rnorm(n,0,1)

dep <- 1 + 2 * x + 3* z + rnorm(n,0,1)

m<-step(lm(dep~x+y+z),direction="backward")
```

I have difficulties extracting the variable names from the final `m$call` and creating the vector.

Comment: Show your actual code along with sample input (and consider tagging your question with [tag:r] tag at the same time)

Comment: I cannot show my actual input but I will take a moment to prepare a simulated example.

Comment: And on this side we can't do divination to guess your input and your code to understand where you're stuck :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does it:

```
n=1000

x <- rnorm(n,0,1)
y <- rnorm(n,0,1)
z <- rnorm(n,0,1)

dep <- 1 + 2*x + 3*z + rnorm(n,0,1)

m<-step(lm(dep~x+y+z),direction="backward")

matt <- attributes(m$terms)
matt$term.labels
#[1] "x" "z"

v <- c("x","y","z")
as.integer(v %in% matt$term.labels)
#[1] 1 0 1
```

Comment: you need to learn to dumpster dive with `str`. Have a look at Hadley Wickhams book "Advanced R" which is available online.